# Foreign key: check table has no key field with the domain

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I have two tables: `ZDEPARTMENT01` and `ZEMPLOY01`.

`ZDEPARTMENT01` has a foreign key `DEPHEAD`, whose data element is `ZPERSONNEL_NO` of domain `ZPERSONNEL_NO` ( NUMC, 10 ). `ZEMPLOY01` has a primary key `EMP_NUM`, whose data element is `ZEMP_NUM` of domain `ZEMP_NUM` ( NUMC, 10 ).

`ZDEPARTMENT01-DEPHEAD` is the foreign key and `ZEMPLOY01-EMP_NUM` is the check key, and  `ZDEPARTMENT01-DEPHEAD` domain `ZPERSONNEL_NO` has value table: `ZEMPLOY01`.

While setting the check table for `ZDEPARTMENT01-DEPHEAD` I got the error **Check table ZEMPLOY01 has no key field with the domain ZPERSONNEL_NO of the field DEPHEAD**

Even though both domains have the same datatype and length (but different domains) the system is unable to recognize the foreign key table and check table relationship.

The document says: The system attempts to assign the key fields of the check table to fields of the table with the same domain. Does it mean in addition to the datatype and the length, the domain names should be same between the foreign key table and the check table?

How to solve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it already says in the message, you'll have to adjust your data elements to use the same domains:

> The check table must have a key field to which the domain of the check
>   field is assigned.

[(documentation)](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/cf/21eb95446011d189700000e8322d00/content.htm)

I'm not entirely sure about this, but I believe the rationale behind this is that this will prevent you from changing one of the table field definitions without changing the other one at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Yes that's what it means. You have two Data Elements: **ZEMP_NUM** and **ZPERSONNEL_NO**. If you double-click on these, in your table, you will navigate to the data element definition. There you will see the **Domain** assigned to each. These should be the same, so make them the same.

Think about it this way:
**Domains** provide structural consistency for data that can appear in multiple places. You wouldn't have an employee id that's 10 digits in some places and 8 in others or it will cause 10-digit records to get truncated. Likewise, if you run out of digits and need to extend your employee id to 11 digits, you want to make sure it's changed everywhere, in every table where it's used. **Domains** let you do this. Domains also let you configure the default look up relationship (value table) or fixed values that can be selected (eg the Employee table).

**Data Elements** provide contextual relevance. You'll notice that in addition to supplying the domain of a data element, you can define the field labels and heading, and you can assign a custom search help. These allow you to display the field to the user in a way that is relevant to the current activity. In this case, you can label the Employee "Department Head", because it would be confusing to have a field meant to hold the ID of the department head and have it display as only "Employee". You could also add a search help that restricts the Employee list to only those flagged as "Managers".

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem are the key fields definitions. The table 'ZEMPLOY01' has the key fields 'CARRIER' and 'EMPNUM' and if you want that the foreign key 'DEPHEAD' of table 'ZDEPARTMENT01' works then you have two options:

1. Change the key fields defined in table 'ZEMPLOY01'. Just set 'EMPNUM' as your only key field and then try to make the relation.
2. Add the field 'CARRIER' to table 'ZDEPARTMENT01' and then try to make the relation.

Please confirm.

Hope it helps.